# Platform-independent way to listen to TCP connections in a Java application

Tags: java, tcp, listener, platform-independent

For context, I'm writing an add-on to a Java-based server program that will calculate the latency of each IP connected to the server based on the recent TCP packet timings. The server API that I'm working with provides no way of doing this.

What I'd like to do is use a TCP listener to listen for all local activity on the server port and store recent time-stamped seq/acks for all IPs. I've looked into some libraries like pcap4j, but due to their platform-specific dependencies this is not ideal as the server software runs on many different operating systems.

Does anyone know of a Java library that can listen to TCP connections and provide the IP and seq/ack numbers? The listener should be able to run in a multi-threaded environment, or otherwise avoid blocking the main thread. I've looked everywhere for something like this to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Java's standard APIs [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html) and [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ServerSocket.html) don't (seem to) offer such functionalty: _provide ... seq/ack numbers_. Leading me to believe that the Java library you want would have to rely on a native (platform-specific) implementation in any case. And so you'd be back at pcap4j. Or are you looking for a Java library which bundles such native code?

Comment: @IvoMori As long as it doesn't require a separate software installation by the user, I'm fine with the library internally referencing OS-specific code.